# Angular nvd3 sunburst does not update with $scope.data change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-nvd3

**Use Case:**
When data changes from the api, `$scope.data` also changes. I could see the data change in html. A sunburst chart update is expected.

Here is the core code:

**Controller:**

```
var grabData=function(){
  $http.get('someApi').then(function success(response){
  $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'sunburstChart',
            width:450,
            height: 450,
            color: d3.scale.category20c(),
            duration: 250,
            mode: 'size',
            useInteractiveGuideline:true,
        }
    };
    $scope.config = {
        visible: true, // default: true
        disabled: false, // default: false
        refreshDataOnly: true, // default: true
        deepWatchOptions: true, // default: true
        deepWatchData: true, // default: true
        deepWatchDataDepth: 2, // default: 2
        debounce: 10 // default: 10
    };
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.data.push({"name":"PORTFOLIO", "children":response.data});
    },function error(response){
      $scope.all = response.statusText;
  });};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
  <nvd3 options="options" data="data" config="config" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
</div>
```

**Issue:**
Now when the data changes from the api, `$scope.data` also changes. I could see the data change in html. But the sunburst chart **does not update at all until I manually refresh the page**.

Comment: Could you prepare a plunker for that? You can fork mine with Angular/NVD3 already in place: http://plnkr.co/N6lWYU

Comment: So I have a service that sends a signal when data at the back-end changes. As soon as the controller gets the signal, the function `grabData()` is called and `$scope.data` gets updated. HTML reflects the data, that means `$scope.data` has changed but the chart does not update. The code is as above ! @Atais

Comment: The `deepWatchData: true` should do the trick and update the graph. It does not, that is why you should try to replicate the issue with plunker. With this approach you will isolate the problem. The issue might be somewhere else in your application.

Comment: Chart should not render at all in case the data was wrong, no? And I'll update the plunker soon.

Comment: Probably it should not, but well... it's javascript.

Comment: I forked your plunker, does not seem to work, check it out @Atais

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117919/discussion-between-thatbird-and-atais).

Answer (score 1):

So the fix was pretty simple, you have to pass refreshDataOnly: false.

`config="{refreshDataOnly: false}"` in your configurations-

`<nvd3 options="options" data="sunburst" config="{refreshDataOnly: false}" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>`